# Have the ID after chosing a value in HTML select

Tags: php

I have the id, surname and the name of a person picked form the database using a query.
So there are an example of my table and the query with variables that I use.

```
+----+--------+---------+
| ID | NAME   | SURNAME |
+====+========+=========+
|  1 | limone | salmone |
+----+--------+---------+
|  2 | john   | bobbino |
+----+--------+---------+

  $queryN = "SELECT `ID`,`NAME`,`SURNAME` FROM `t_people` WHERE 1";
  $sql = mysqli_query($con , $queryN);
  $people = array();
  $id = array();
  while($row = $sql -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
      $people[] = $row["NAME"]." ". $row["SURNAME"];//limone salmone
      $id[] = $row["ID"];//1
    }
```

I would like to have in output in an HTML select the name and the surname of the selected person and the ID of the person chosen when I pass in an other page. 
I have this code below that works pretty good, but with this solution, I have in other page only the value of `$people`. It is a problem, because in the database could be more than one person with same name and surname.

```
    <label class="control-label" for="NCPersona">Seleziona il nome della persona</label>
        <select name="NCPersona" id="validationDefaultUsername" class="form-control" required>
          <?php
          foreach($people as $value) { ?>
          <option value="<?= $value?>"><?= $value?></option>
          <?php
      } ?>
        </select>
```

So i thinked that the best thing to do is pass the id of that person through the pages.
How I can do it?
Maybe using the id in the value camp? Thanks to everyone! :)

There are an example of my code above

```html
        <label for="NCPersona">Select the person's name</label>
            <select name="NCPersona" required>
              <option value="limone salmone">limone salmone</option>
              <option value="john bobbino">john bobbino</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would do is retrieve the table data and build an array of values like this:

```
$queryN = "SELECT * FROM `t_people`";
$sql = mysqli_query($con , $queryN);
$people = array();
$id = array();
while($row = $sql -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $people[] = array(
    'id' => $row["ID"],
    'name' => $row["NAME"]." ". $row["SURNAME"],
  );
}
```

Then after you have the array ready, you can build you select box with ID as value like this:

```
<label class="control-label" for="NCPersona">Seleziona il nome della persona</label>
<select name="NCPersona" id="validationDefaultUsername" class="form-control" required>
  <?php
  foreach($people as $value) { ?>
  <option value="<?= $value['id'] ?>"><?= $value['name'] ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Then any user specific query should look by the supplied ID and not the name.

```
$id = 'user id here';
$queryN = sprintf("SELECT `ID`,`NAME`,`SURNAME` FROM `t_people` WHERE %d", $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql request how does it work? It should be like this:

```
"SELECT `ID`,`NAME`,`SURNAME` FROM `t_people` WHERE `id`=1"
```

you do not have an  `id`

Where is your ID here

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass id and name, you should not separate them. You can try this code

```
$queryN = "SELECT `ID`,`NAME`,`SURNAME` FROM `t_people` WHERE id=1";
$sql = mysqli_query($con , $queryN);
$people = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)) {
    $people[] = $row;
}
```

And for the dropdown

```
<label class="control-label" for="NCPersona">Seleziona il nome della persona</label>
    <select name="NCPersona" id="validationDefaultUsername" class="form-control" required>
      <?php
          foreach($people as $value) { ?>
          <option value="<?= $value->id ?>"><?= $value->name." ".$value->surname ?></option>
      <?php
          } 
      ?>
    </select>
```